# search for a word in file in bash and execute something if the word is present

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have written the following line as a bash:

```
nmcli nm status id "My VPN id"> /home/Desktop/1.txt
```

So I want to check the id status and save it in the `1.txt` file.

Now I want to search in `1.txt` file and if it finds the word `"connected"` then do nothing and if it does not find it run the following line:

```
nmcli con up id "My VPN id"
```

How can I write the search part?

**Edit:**
I made a bash script on a document on Desktop (with a name `"s.sh"` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

nmcli nm status id 1> /home/Desktop/1.txt
grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt || nmcli con up id 1
```

and edit the crontab as follows:
[image]

Saved the file.
But the cron does not work!

Comment: check return code of `grep "connected" 1.txt`. 0/1 whether pattern is present or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a command only if `connected` is not in `1.txt`:

```
grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt || nmcli con up id "My VPN id"
```

`grep string file` will return exit code 0 (success) if the regex `string` is found in `file`.  To execute a command only if `grep` returns with fail, we use the shell's logical-or: `||`.

As an alternative, we can use a full if-then statement:

```
if ! grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt
then
    nmcli con up id "My VPN id"
fi
```

Again, we only want to run the command if `grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt` returns fail.  To do that, we use `!` to negate the return code.  In this way the command will run if `grep` returns with a fail code.

The `-q` option to `grep` tells `grep` to be quiet.  When used with `-q`, instead of printing output, `grep` will simply set a return code.

#### Crontab

To run this command every hour on the hour, run `crontab -e`.  This will raise an editor.  In the editor, add the line:

```
0 * * * *  /bin/grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt || /path/to/nmcli con up id "My VPN id"
```

Now, save the file and exit the editor.

For more information on the very useful `crontab`, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+crontab).

#### Without crontab

```
while sleep 60m
do
    grep -q connected /home/Desktop/1.txt || nmcli con up id "My VPN id"
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that helped.
and if I want to make this script run every 60 min. What should I do?!

Comment: To run it every hour, I would put it in `crontab`.

Comment: and how to do it, please? :D
or where can i find information about using crontab to schedule?

Comment: @P.A.M See updated answer for some `crontab` info.  `crontab` is very useful.  I recommend reading [a tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+crontab) on it.

Comment: thanks so much for your help.

Comment: my crontab doesnt work  :(

Comment: @P.A.M _"doesnt work"_  That is obviously not enough information for anyone to be able to diagnose a problem and offer help.  As an alternative,  I updated the answer with a simple bash script which will run your program every 60 minutes.